# How do I extract the value from an xpath expression

Tags: xpath

I have a query that looks like...

`/freeStyleBuild/artifact[fileName=starts-with(.,'imc')]/fileName`

But it returns the data inside tags:

`<fileName>imc5.0.0.5078.zip</fileName>`

But I just want:
`"imc5.0.0.5078.zip"`

I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: So am I. What's the difference between the two? They appear identical to me.

Comment: what are you using to do this? There must be .text or something like that to extract the value from tag

Comment: I want to put the value in a script. I'd like to avoid having to strip off the <fileName >.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way using additional `/text()` at the end :

```
/freeStyleBuild/artifact[fileName=starts-with(.,'imc')]/fileName/text()
```